# Terraform: Docker provider does not respect insecure-registries?

Tags: docker, terraform

I am trying to pull a Docker image from a local Artifactory when the digest of the image changed. But I am confused about Terrform configuration and its relation to the installed Docker Desktop.

The Terrform script starts with:

```
terraform {
 required_providers {
  docker = {
    source = "terraform-providers/docker"
  }
 }
}

provider "docker" {
  host = "npipe:////.//pipe//docker_engine"

  registry_auth {
    address= "ip:port"
    username = "my-username"
    password = "my-password"
  }
}

data "docker_registry_image" "my-image" {
  name = "ip:port/repository-name/my-image:version"
}

resource "docker_image" "my-image" {
  name = "my-image-name"
  pull_triggers = ["data.docker_registry_image.my-image.sha256_digest"]
  keep_locally = true
}
```

I added the registry *ip:port* to the insecure-registries so that also Terraform has access to it.

The problem is that the insecure-registries from Docker Desktop is somehow ignored by Terraform (Docker provider) because I get the response:

```
Error: Got error when attempting to fetch image version from registry: Error during registry request: Get https://ip:port/v2/repository-name/my-image:version: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client.

  on script.tf line 20, in data "docker_registry_image" "my-image":
  20: data "docker_registry_image" "my-image" {
```

Can anyone help? Does somebody know why insecue-registries set in Docker Desktop does not apply here?

Comment: Are you saying you've configured `insecure-registries` in your `daemon.json` config file?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Yes, in Docker Desktop under Docker Engine is added my registry, and I can do docker pull, so I am sure it works. The problem has only Terraform, after I've added the data "docker_registry_image" object.

Comment: Looks like this is only enabled when `TF_ACC` is set to `1` (or higher) as it's only enabled during acceptance testing: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-docker/blob/ccb7c6e8abe0fae89d115347c0677b5c0f45e2bf/docker/data_source_docker_registry_image.go#L85-L96. You could raise a feature request to support config allowing for insecure registries or try working around it by setting that environment variable. I'd err for the former but the latter might help right now.

Comment: In line 98 I see that the protocol https is hardcoded, which would denote that the parameter `insecure-registries` is not supported by Terraform.

Comment: Your Docker registry is HTTP and not HTTPS with just missing or self signed certs?

Comment: The Docker registry doesn't belong to me and it doesn't have any cert, that's why it is HTTP only. If Terraform doesn't allow to use such HTTP registers in conjunction with checking image digest, then I think a certificate must be installed, because there is no other way to work this around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found out the answer. Here is the link https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-docker/blob/ccb7c6e8abe0fae89d115347c0677b5c0f45e2bf/docker/data_source_docker_registry_image.go#L85-L96 to the source code of the `terraform-provider-docker` plugin  where we can see in the line 98 that the protocol `https` is hardcoded, when getting the image digest:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://"+registry+"/v2/"+image+"/manifests/"+tag, nil)
```

This is the answer why the `insecure-registries` property is not taken into the account.